# How to bind to class variable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

How can I bind TextBlock to MyListClass.myText?

```
//code behind
public cList MyListClass = new cList();

public class cList : DependencyObject
{    
     public string myText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(myTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(myTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty myTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("myText", typeof(string), typeof(cList), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public cList()
    {
        myText = "Test";
    }
}
```

What should I set as Source

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myText, Source=???}" />
```

Comment: I recommend not using a source here, and instead setting the TextBlock's DataContext to your cList object. You can do this either in c# or in XAML, which are you looking to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set `DataContext`, it will automatically bind `myText` property to `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myText}" Name="somename" />
```

codebehind:

```
somename.DataContext= cList;
```

or simply :

```
this.DataContext = cList;
```

Comment: Thanks! This would have saved me 2 weeks if I knew this a year ago!

Comment: welcome and now you have learned I also learned same way and still learning things

Answer (score 1):

Its not very clear what you are looking for here. Dependency objects and properties are used so that you can bind *to* them, not use them for another binding.

That being said, assuming the DataContext for the TextBlock is set to the cList object, you don't need to use `Source` at all, just leave it at myText. If the datacontext is set to a object that holds a cList (say in a property called `MyCList`), you set the path to `MyCList.myText`.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to bind the text property of Textblock with the class property, instead of setting DataContext every time when text value changes.

Change your code for more accurate Binding.

Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface to this class and implement its methods as follows.

```
    public class cList : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {    

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public string myText
        {
            get 
            { 
                 return (string)GetValue(myTextProperty); 
            }
            set 
            { 
                SetValue(myTextProperty, value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged("myText"); 
            }
        }

        .....
        .....
    }
```

and XAML as follows:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding myText}" ElementName="YourXAMLPageName" />
```

Comment: I did not need to to update DataContext every time text value changes. I only had to set datacontext on window init as per accepted answer and any change of the value will be automatically shown on the window

Comment: Ya, it may be correct for your use, but it cannot be useful in every senario..Eg: If the text changes while you are in that same page, the init will not call and so you have to set datacontext to reflet the change.. In short, i am trying to say that Binding using NotifyPropertyChange is the better way as per .Net experts..